# Terraform says I have to create NS records but they appear to be created by default?

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53

The [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_zone#public-subdomain-zone) for the `aws_route53_zone` resource state:

> Public Subdomain Zone
>
> For use in subdomains, note that you need to create a
> aws_route53_record of type NS as well as the subdomain zone.

```json
resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "example.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "dev" {
  name = "dev.example.com"

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "dev-ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "dev.example.com"
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = aws_route53_zone.dev.name_servers
}
```

However when I create a public subdomain it already contains an ns record - are the docs out of date or are there other steps I need to follow, such as deleting the ns record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you're exploring here is more of a general DNS quirk than a Route53-specific or Terraform-specific problem.

When resolving a domain name the DNS client will recursively resolve parts of the name in turn, starting with the root nameservers to know which DNS servers are responsible for `com`, and then from there to which servers are responsible for `example.com`, and then finally from there to `dev.example.com`.

In order to answer that question the *parent* domain must contain `NS` records telling the client which nameservers to re-ask the question to.

Route53 by default creates the `NS` records by which a zone describes *its own* authoritative nameservers. However, a DNS client can't find those records unless the *parent* zone also contains the same records.

With all of that said, what your example Terraform configuration is doing here is declaring that we need to copy the `NS` record values from `aws_route53_zone.dev` into the parent zone `aws_route53_zone.main`, with the same hostnames in both places.

When a client looks up this hostname, it will *first* ask one of the nameservers given in `aws_route53_zone.main.name_servers` (assuming that you've registered them correctly in your domain registrar's settings), and those servers will respond with these records declared by `aws_route53_record.dev-ns` and so therefore the client will be able to re-ask the question to the authoritative nameservers and get a final answer.

In order for this to be useful you'll need to include at least one non-`NS` record in the `dev.example.com` zone too, so that the final question sent to the `aws_route53_zone.dev.name_servers` will return `A`, `AAAA`, `MX`, `CNAME`, etc.